# Conditional probability problem with Bayes' Rule

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

The question is as follows:

> A crime is committed by one of two suspects, A and B. Initially, there is equal
>   evidence against both of them. In further investigation at the crime scene, it is
>   found that the guilty party had a blood type found in $10\%$ of the population.
>   Suspect A does match this blood type, whereas the blood type of Suspect B is
>   unknown. Given this new information, what is the probability that A is the guilty party?

My solution:

> Let $A$ be the event that A is guilty. Let $B$ be the event that B is guilty. Let $C$ be the event of having the guilty blood type. It follow that:

$$P(A|C)=\frac{P(C|A)P(A)}{P(C)}=\frac{(1)(0.5)}{(0.1)}=5$$

Does anyone know what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: probability more than 1 shows that there is definitely something wrong...

Comment: You have not said what the event $C$ is, but I suspect you will find that when combined with the background information *"A crime is committed by one of two suspects, A and B"* you may find your value of  $P(C)$ could be $P(C|A)P(A)+P(C|B)P(B) = 0.5$ making $P(A\mid C)=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last probability should be

$$P(A|C)=\frac{P(C|A)P(A)}{P(C)}=\frac{P(C|A)P(A)}{P(C|A)P(A) + P(C|B)P(B)}$$

where $P(A) = P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$ as one of the suspects $A$ or $B$ did it, a priori.

We know $P(C|A) = 1$, as we measured the blood type of $A$.

We don't know $B$'s so we must assume $P(C|B) = \frac{1}{10}$ as this is the population fraction.

Now filling these in I get $\frac{10}{11}$.

Comment: Hmmm, why isn't $P(C)$ just equal to $0.1$?

Comment: @zoom we are working in a limited world. Only A and B are the population and A we know

Comment: **Did you typo in your last comment overhead?** *"Only A and B are the population and A we know"*???? *"A we know"* **is ungrammatical**.

Comment: @evolva it’s short for “only for A we know the blood type “. Not a typo.